# My css files don't run in my single blog page

Tags: laravel

I use laravel 8, I'm creating a blog. The problem is when i click one of my posts for seeing the single blog page, the page don't come due to problem to see all the css.

```
'''

      <!-- Bootstrap Css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
    <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('css/font-awesome.min.css')}}">
    <!-- Slick Nav CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('css/slicknav.min.css')}}">
    <!-- Cube Portfolio CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('css/cubeportfolio.min.css')}}">
    <!-- Magnific Popup CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('css/magnific-popup.min.css')}}">
    <!-- Fancy Box CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('css/jquery.fancybox.min.css')}}">
    <!-- Nice Select CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('css/niceselect.css')}}">
    <!-- Owl Carousel CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('css/owl.theme.default.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('css/owl.carousel.min.css')}}">
    <!-- Slick Slider CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('css/slickslider.min.css')}}">
    <!-- Animate CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('css/animate.min.css')}}">
    
    <!-- Radix StyleShet CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('css/reset.css')}}"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('style.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('css/responsive.css')}}">    

    <!-- Radix Color CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('css/color/color1.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="#" id="colors">
```

'''

[What my single blog page looks like [][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLVUY.png)

if i don't use the stylesheets 'reset.css' it looks like :
[single blog page without stylesheet reset.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRY0N.png)

Comment: please add the image description, otherwise the link looks spammy

Comment: 1) Do you really need all of those stylesheets?
2) Start testing, remove half of them and see if your page loads, trade them back in for the other half. By dividing the scripts in half and then half again with testing, you should be able to discern the one(s) causing you the trouble.

Comment: do the URLs generated by your `url` calls look correct? If you follow those links what response do you get?

Comment: Yes, I need the most of these stylesheets. I tested all af them and the problem is with the file "reset.css" I don't know exactly what is the problem with this file. But it is the cause which affect my single blog page

Comment: @lagbox Yes i think  the generated url is correct, look at in the images that i added

Answer (score 0):

You can use asset helper instead of url

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/reset.css')}}">
```

Comment: I try, but it doesn't work

Comment: Put your link as first link , this kind of issue usually happen and often one file affects on other files

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work too.